# Python Openpyxl return a sheet name which doesn't exist

Tags: openpyxl, python-3.6

In my excel file, I have only three worksheet: "Slot 14", "Data Display", and "Ctrl Value".

When I use openpyxl to load excel file, it returns other worksheet which doesn't exist: ['Slot 14', 'DETAILNO-14', 'DETAIL-14', 'PNO-14', 'DATA-14', 'Data Display', 'Ctrl Value']

#### Following is my code

```
filepath=r'D:\Users\chshiu\Desktop\filename.xlsx'

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filepath)
wb.get_sheet_names()
```

I don't think there is something wrong in my code. I am wondering maybe the problem is from excel file itself? I have VBA code inside the excel file.

More information:
I use Python3 in windows.
Because openpyxl cannot load xls file now so I save my original xls file into xlsx file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible that your file contains hidden sheets. Older versions of Excel use things called Macrosheets for some of the GUI controls. openpyxl just reports what it finds.